# How can I reference classes in a .net executable?

Tags: c#, .net

IL disassembler shows classes in a .Net executable that I would like to use in my project. How could I use those classes from my own project?

Comment: If you don't own the EXE, you may want to be wary of licensing issues.  The license for most software without source code typically doesn't allow reuse in this way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your project on Visual Studio add a reference to that executable and you should have access to the public classes it defines. An executable is an assembly like any other.