# Warning message when created a new Form

Tags: c#, winforms, compiler-warnings

When i added a new from to my existing project, It shows this Warning Message

> The type 'Banking_and_Financial_System.UserLoginForm' in 'D:\Internship
>   Project\Banking_and_Financial_System\Banking_and_Financial_System\UserLoginForm.cs'
>   conflicts with the imported type
>   'Banking_and_Financial_System.UserLoginForm' in 'D:\Internship
>   Project\Banking_and_Financial_System\Banking_and_Financial_System\bin\Debug\Banking_and_Financial_System.exe'.
>   Using the type defined in 'D:\Internship
>   Project\Banking_and_Financial_System\Banking_and_Financial_System\UserLoginForm.cs'.

in the Program.cs file on the Line below
        Application.Run(new UserLoginForm());

Then I tried to modify the Existing form changed its name to Writeoff.cs then compiled it, I got the same above warning message.

Comment: `Then i tried to modify the Existing form changed its name to Writeoff.cs then compiled it, i got the same above warning message.` Did you also rename the class or namespace, or just the filename?

Comment: i changed the file name , then it automatically changed all other things

Comment: i got this error when i renamed it 
is it something with the Form name, is there any other thing like named Writeoff in the system

Comment: no this is a old form named Form1.cs, i only changed its name..
and no form named Writeoff exist in the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tells you that:

- In `UserLoginForm.cs`, there is a type called `Banking_and_Financial_System.UserLoginForm`,
- there is also a type calle `Banking_and_Financial_System.UserLoginForm` in `Banking_and_Financial_System.exe`

These two sound like the same thing to me, but it seems as if the latter of them is refering to a compiled version of your application. I find that a little strange, and I'm not sure about the technical details here, but it sounds like an accdidental inclusion causing a conflict.

Did you really mean to refer to the `.exe`-file in your debug-folder? If you've added such a reference explicitly, you should try to remove it.

**Update**:

Explanation: [**You can refer to and access public classes directly from a compiled .exe**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576275/how-can-i-reference-classes-in-a-net-executable).

Comment: I'd love to know the technical details here if this is correct, I don't know how you could possibly get a class name out of a compiled exe in this way

Comment: Thanks you to @Sayse and @ DGibbs also

Comment: @Sayse I must admit, I was not aware of this possibility, but apparently, you can access public stuff in a compiled .exe directly. Updated my answer with a link to another SO question.

Comment: ah right, very nice to know! I think my applications just became a lot more air tight..

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the file names of the forms and to do with the namespaces of the files.

You should specify the namespace for this call

`Application.Run(new [insertcorrectnamespace].UserLoginForm());`

What the error is telling you is it doesn't know which user login form you want to use as the class has knowledge of two with the same name but different namespaces

Comment: @DGibbs, I appologise if this looks like im stealing your answer (I'm not), I've only just read the comments